# Backup github repository, branches and commits?

Tags: github, repository, backup

I want to backup everything including master & other branches & commits on my local & create new repository using different account.

Which steps should i follow ? (bundle, mirror or clone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To backup your local, one of the following is enough

Option 1.
Just copy the project folder to a new place.

Option 2

1. Copy the hidden .git/ folder to a new_project_folder.
2. Run `git checkout master` in that folder.

Option 3

1. Create a new_project_folder.
2. `cd path/to/new_project_folder

Now, you need to push to a remote repository. Do it just as you did with previous repo, but use new credentials.

- with GitHub gui tool
- with `git remote add ...`

Comment: Now I read the answer and see that it's not complete. Don't use Option 3  )

Answer (score 0):

The entire git repository is stored within the .git folder, so just do the following:

1) git clone [github clone url]
2) put the cloned folder somewhere safe.
3) create a new account or just create a new repository, or simply fork the project.